# How to mock API calls with axios in Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, axios

I'm new to testing and I have some questions about mocking API and axios instance with ES6 class.

I have an `index.js`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Pushkin {
  constructor() {
    this.con = undefined;
  }

  connect(quizAPIUrl) {
    this.con = axios.create({
      baseURL: quizAPIUrl,
    });
  }
  
  prepExperimentRun(userID) {
    const postData = {
      user_id: userID,
    };
    return this.con.post('/startExperiment', postData);
  }
  
  // ......
}
```

I tried several methods to test it:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import Pushkin from '../src/index';

jest.mock('axios');

const quizURL = './api/quiz';
axios.create.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(quizURL));

const pushkinClient = new Pushkin();

test('connect to quiz api url', () => {
  pushkinClient.connect(quizURL);
  // Pushkin { con: Promise { './api/quiz' } }
  pushkinClient.con.then((data) => expect(data).toEqual(quizURL));
});

test('prepExp', () => {
  const postData = { data: [{ user_id: 123456 }] };
  axios.post.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(postData));
  pushkinClient.prepExperimentRun(123456).then((data) => expect(data).toBe(postData));
});
```

When I run the second test `prepExp`, it throws an error `TypeError: this.con.post is not a function`. And `this.con` is `Promise { './api/quiz' }`.

How should I mock the `quizAPIurl` in `connect(quizAPIurl)` instead of just hardcoding it? After that, what is the correct way to mock a axios instance and test POST requests? Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't test axios' `post()` - it's safe to assume that it works as it should. It would be valid to test that `post()` is called with the correct params though.

Comment: @Yorkshireman Could you please be more specific that how I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html Something like `expect(mockCallback.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe(42);` (`calls[0][0]` is what you have called `mockCallback()` with - specifically the first parameter of the first call)

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/68200193/1143126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you didn't mock your `create()` method right

`axios.create.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(quizURL));`

This will only gives a `Promise<string>` back which does not contains `post()` method. So, of course, it will be "not a function".

One solution is that you can mock an object with a post method:

```
axios.create.mockImplementation(() => { get: () => {...} });
```

Another way, which could be smarter but I didn't test, simply returns axois itself.

```
axios.create.mockImplementation(() => axios);

...

axios.post.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(postData));
```

Comment: I'd steer away from "mocking the behaviour of axios and then testing the mock behaves as it should" which is essentially what has been done here. Of course the mock's `get` or `post` methods will return the data - you've programmed the mock to do that.